# How to connect to the socket.io on the domain?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://ipadress:port');
```

Server side:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(port);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    etc
});
```

How i can use domain for connect to socket.io? He connected only by ip.  Just if i use this:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://domain.com:port');
```

I get only errors with connection(

Comment: What kind of errors do you get?  What does it say in the debug console in the browser?  Are they CORS errors (cross origin)?  If so, then you have to enable CORS on the server.

Comment: It does work with domain names of course. What kind of errors do you get?